# JSON Parse with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, api

completely beginner here.  I have the jquery library.  I make a call to an api that returns json.  i would like to use the parseJSON function within the jquery library to parse it.  simply put, i have no idea how to do so.

I can find the function within the jquery library, it looks like so:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
    if ( typeof data !== "string" || !data ) {
        return null;
    }

    // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
    data = jQuery.trim( data );

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
    // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
    if ( rvalidchars.test( data.replace( rvalidescape, "@" )
        .replace( rvalidtokens, "]" )
        .replace( rvalidbraces, "")) ) {

        return ( new Function( "return " + data ) )();

    }
    jQuery.error( "Invalid JSON: " + data );
},
```

How do i send my json through that?

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsonObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the jQuery AJAX commands, most of them take a dataType parameter.  Setting dataType to 'json' will automatically parse the returned data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

In this case data will end up being an object based on the JSON returned from the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) function, you can access your API endpoint and have the response parsed all in one call.

```
$.getJSON("/my_resource.json", function(data) {
  // Use data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's parseJSON() function will convert the json to a javascript object.

if your json is, for example:

```
{ "firstname" : "john", "lastname" : "doe" }
```

then when you use parseJSON, you can access the properties like so:

```
var json = '{ "firstname" : "john", "lastname" : "doe" }';
var person = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

console.log(person.firstname); //will show john
console.log(person.lastname); //will show doe
```

that should get you started. for more, read the doc here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/